# JAXB - flag 'required' from XmlAttribute being ignored on primitive types

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

I have some problem while trying to use the schemagen tool from JAXB library to generate a Schema for my project. The problem is that the annotation `@XmlAttribute` is not being parsed properlly.

```
- src
 - teste
  - entity
```

So, the problem is that for some classes, the flag `required` in `XmlAttribute` is being ignored completly by the schemagen task.

I'll paste here some examples of classes and the generated schema so you can understand what is going on

```
package teste.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public abstract class Class2 {

    @XmlAttribute(required=false)
    public String stringNotRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    public String stringRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=false)
    public int anotherIntNotRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    public int anotherIntRequired;

}

package teste.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Class1 extends Class2 {

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    public Integer integerRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=false)
    public Integer integerNotRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=false)
    public int intNotRequired;

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    public int intRequired;

    public Class1() {
    }
}
```

My package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "t", namespaceURI = "http://test.com"),
namespace = "http://test.com",
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED,
attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
package teste.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

When I run the `schemagen` task, I got this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://test.com" xmlns:t="http://test.com" xmlns:tns="http://test.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="class1">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:class2">
        <xs:sequence/>
        <xs:attribute name="integerRequired" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="integerNotRequired" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:attribute name="intNotRequired" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="intRequired" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="class2" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="stringNotRequired" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="stringRequired" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="anotherIntNotRequired" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="anotherIntRequired" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is my Ant Task

```
<target name="generate-schema" >
    <path id="mycp">
        <fileset dir="lib/jaxb/lib\">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="lib" >
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="dist" >
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef name="schemagen" classname="com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask">
        <classpath refid="mycp"/>
    </taskdef>

    <mkdir dir="schema"/>

    <schemagen srcdir="src/teste/entity" destdir="schema" >
        <classpath refid="mycp"/>
        <schema namespace="http://test.com" file="full.xsd" />            
    </schemagen>
</target>
```

Comment: _I've got the file full.xsd correctly, and the other schema2.xsd with the reamaining types and elements_ I didn't get you. What are the contents of `full.xsd` and `schema2.xsd`? Why is there two files generated? I guess, if you other classes in your package (like `Thing`) then you have to annotate those too.

Comment: Yes, I got two more packages that are being generated as a part of the schema, and they are needed =]

Comment: Okay, so I'm supposed to guess what files are being generated at _your_ end, right? Oh wait, see what I did there? … Given your input, a single class (which, by the way, extends some _other_ class you didn't supply) I've tried to create a test scenario, so you could see what are the factors that need to be changed in order to tweak you XML output. If this isn't enough to solve your problem (which by the way I didn't really get anymore), then try to rewrite your question. See [this website](http://sscce.org/) for guidelines on how to do it.

Comment: Ok completly rewrote the question, I hope you can now understand what is going on here.

Comment: So we're back to square one, ain't we? The problem here is that you present the actual schema you got, but given _these_ classes `schemagen` will fail miserably while compiling them, because there aren't annotated. Also, if you have two packages, both of them having classes which supposed to be XML types, then you'll have to compile both of them with `schemagen`. With `<schemagen srcdir="src/com/fortresswars/entity" ...` you only compile one of them. _Simplify_ your question (the actual classes) and isolate your problem, and state your actual problem after that.

Comment: Well, that doesn't explain why one class without annontations get compiled correctly and other doesn't. I've ran all kinds of testes I can aorund here, but got no luck getting it to work. No class inside `src/com/fortresswars/entity` and subfolders works with the annotation `@XmlAttribute(required=false)`, they all have the exact same behavior. And, when I `schemagen` `src/com/fortresswars/scripting` the classes inside that package gets compiled correctly. I edited the quesiton to add the annotations, but still it refuses to work.

Comment: I added a new question over here, maybe that's the source of the problem, with thos eprimitive types, but I didn't see any documentation about this, so it's weird.

Comment: I would say quite likely primitive types are the problem.  What do you expect to have in your expirationTime field when that attribute is missing?  Zero?  How will you tell that apart from an actual zero value having been present?  In other words, there isn't a way to represent the missing attribute when the type of the field is primitive.  You need it to be an object type so that null can be used for that purpose.

Comment: Ok completly reqwrote the question again. @Kevin I have used others XML parsers and I have done this, all they did was to attribute the default value or the primitive type/

Comment: So anyone can answer this new question?

Comment: @SHiRKiT You won't be able to create an _optional_ attribute from a primitive type with `schemagen` and that's it. Even if you can can find some workaround it wouldn't be too straightforward and you're better off with a boxed primitive. `schemagen` can create a one-to-one mapping between a boxed primitive and a schema attribute, but this isn't true with normal primitives.

Comment: And If I generate the schema but without using the schemagen, could I map the normal java primitives to optional attributes?

Comment: @SHiRKiT No—or at least I don't know any alternatives better than I've already described in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Do I need annotations on the classes for the namespace to get output correctly?

Probably. I've created a setup similar to yours.

### `Test.java`

```
package test;

...

@XmlType(name = "test", namespace = "http://test.com", propOrder = "b")
@XmlRootElement(name = "test", namespace = "http://test.com")
public final class Test {

  @XmlAttribute(required = false)
  public String a;

  @XmlElement
  public String b;

  public Test() {}
}
```

### `package-info.java`

```
@XmlSchema(xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "tns", namespaceURI = "http://test.com"),
           namespace = "http://test.com",
           elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
           attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

### `build.xml` (snippet, based on OP's input)

```
<schemagen srcdir="<path-to-test-package>" destdir=".">
  <classpath refid="<classpath-refid>" />
  <schema namespace="http://test.com" file="test.xsd" />
</schemagen>
```

### `test.xsd` (output)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema 
  attributeFormDefault="qualified"
  elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0"
  targetNamespace="http://test.com"
  xmlns:tns="http://test.com"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="test" type="tns:test"/>

  <xs:complexType name="test" final="extension restriction">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="tns:a"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:attribute name="a" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

<sub>(I've used the prefix `tns` because JAXB will generate and use that instead of any prefix that was specified in `@XmlNs`.)</sub>

Given the files above XJC's `SchemaGen` produces the desired results—if I have a required attribute, then it'll be generated as such; if I set `required=false`, then it won't.

The main thing here is the `@XmlType` annotation on the `Test` class. You just can't live without that if you handcraft your classes. (The `@XmlRootElement` isn't necessary, so it depends on your use-case if you want it or not.) This tells JAXB which namespace does the `Test` class (which represents a schema *type* by the way) belongs when `SchemaGen` processes it.

The `package-info.java` serves *almost* the same purpose but at a *schema* level. If a package contains this file (and the annotations shown above) and `SchemaGen` encounters, then it'll know that the classes (schema types) in that package belongs to the namespace specified in the package level annotations. (Again, if you doing things by hand this is a must.) Other than this, `SchemaGen` uses the namespace declared in this file to send the output to the file you specified in `<schema namespace="http://test.com" file="test.xsd" />`. Without it the generated file's name is always `schema1.xsd` (or similar).

### Multiple packages

If you want to group several classes located in multiple packages into one namespace, then you'll have to apply the *same* package level annotations on all of the packages (like in the `package-info.java` snippet above—the namespace prefix used must be `tns`, because of the JAXB limitation described earlier).

`schemagen` of course needs to be ordered to compile *both* packages. In your `build.xml` the `schemagen` task's `srcdir` should encompass both packages.

If you have a structure similar to this

```
.
|-- x
|   |-- A.java             # JAXB
|   |-- B.java             # POJO
|   `-- package-info.java  # http://test.com
`-- y
    |-- C.java             # JAXB
    `-- package-info.java  # http://test.com
```

you can tell the `schemagen` task to compile only `A` and `C` like this

```
<schemagen srcdir="." destdir="." >
  <schema namespace="http://test.com" file="test.xsd" />
  <include name="x/A.java" />
  <include name="y/C.java" />
</schemagen>
```

### Optional and required attributes

There is a [short section in the official JAXB tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_6_2_7_3-Class-Fields-as-Attributes-XmlAttribute.html#Class%20Fields%20as%20Attributes:%20XmlAttribute) on attributes, which unfortunately doesn't say a thing about primitive Java types and XML Schema types in particular.

The shortcoming you're experiencing isn't a JAXB defect in my opinion, rather a Java *oddity*: primitive types can't be null, which is good and bad at the same time.

You can solve this by changing your primitive attribute

```
@XmlAttribute
public int attribute;

@XmlAttribute
public Integer attribute;
```

<sub>(I've found a [mailing list thread regarding this same issue](http://glassfish.10926.n7.nabble.com/primitive-types-int-double-etc-instead-of-class-types-td60647.html), maybe you're interested in it.)</sub>